# Cannot connect to TFS from Windows XP

Tags: tfs, vb6, windows-xp, azure-devops

I have a Team Foundation Server 2013 installed on a server on a domain. I can connect to this server from my domain account using VS 2012.

I also have a virtual machine which runs on Windows XP and NOT part of the domain (login as a local user). I have a VB6 project running on this VM and I want to connect to the TFS to share and control my VB6 code but I keep on getting The Request Failed with HTTP status 404: Not found.

I tried creating a local user on the server with the same name as the user I use for VM but it didn't work. I cannot join the VM to the domain as well.

Hope someone has tackled this and shed me some light.

Comment: Try connecting with a browser from that VM.

Comment: It asked for credentials and gave my domain user credentials and it logged me in and now I can see the projects on the browser but still cannot connect from VB6

Comment: I suggest you install Visual Studio Express on that VM and try to connect from there. I suspect it will work. That suggests that you're missing the patch or patches to VB6 which permit it to work with TFS. Sorry, I don't have a link to the patches.

Comment: Tried but I get an error TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server
I'm using VS team viewer 2005 on XP VM

Comment: I deliberately suggested installing VS Express. In particular, VS Express 2013. That will rule out any effects caused by ancient software, like VS2005.

Comment: Did you install the MSSCCI provider on the VB6 machine? It is required to connect to TFS using VB6.

Comment: Btw, this link might help you a bit: http://www.vlaquest.com/2013/06/small-guide-to-using-vb6-with-tfs-2012/